# How to use add condition to one column

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to use this and condition to get all the records using "AND"

[image]

```
SELECT *
FROM `setting` 
WHERE value= 'Men' AND value='Bags'
```

Comment: WHERE tests each row separately and independently by other rows. But the value in ONE row may be either 'Men' or 'Bags', but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want *both* tags.  One method is aggregation:

```
SELECT idproduct
FROM `setting` 
WHERE value IN ('Men', 'Bags')
GROUP BY idproduct
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

This assumes no duplicate values on a given product.

Comment: In a case if i search value like 'Girl' so in this i got the records of Men,Bags too that is wrong,because of its in 'IN' condition.

Comment: I need to get the value like value if 'Men','Bags' and 'Girl'. how can i achieve that ?

Comment: @RahulDave . . . Add the values to the `IN` list and change the `2` to the number of values.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use 'or'

```
SELECT * FROM setting WHERE value= 'Men' or value='Bags'
```

Answer (score 0):

**AND** will not work in this situation. You must use **OR**

```
SELECT * FROM setting WHERE value= 'Men' or value='Bags'
```